# What (sans-serif) font should I use for an OS X application?

Tags: fonts, typography, mac, ios, windows

Currently working on an application, which will be released on Multiple platforms, targeting OS X and Windows devices first, followed by iOS release. The current focus is on the OS X version, which will be released first.

During the design process, I have opted for Myriad Pro. Which suits the application in various areas very well. i.e. Titles, Labels, Menu Texts etc.

After some research though I have released it is not shipped with Macs or other OS.

I am currently working on OS X Lion and have no access to Avenir, however, I had the chance to try Helvetica and H. Neue, which looks fine but does not fit as well as Myriad Pro.

- What fonts should I try to use?
- What would be your suggestions as experienced designers on the
  subject?

Thank you

Comment: Arial is always a safe bet..

Comment: What are your limitations? I assume it has to be a system font?

Comment: I don't really have limitations other than not wanting to pay money to use or distribute a custom font. I'm ok to use different fonts on different systems if necessary. And I'm probably ok to use a custom font that looks good as well. Myriad so far, looks most suitable for the project though but I am not good with fonts so something else might be equally good looking or even better and I am open for all suggestions and recommendations of your favourites. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The default system font for OS X is [Lucida Grande](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucida_Grande), so if you want a native look I'd recommend that. It's also more of a humanist style like Myriad.

If you don't like that, check out [Geneva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geneva_%28typeface%29). That's also a very "Apple" font (albeit more of a historical footnote than practical reality in my experience)

Beyond that, [Gill Sans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gill_Sans) and [Futura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futura_%28typeface%29) are quality choices, though they definitely wouldn't have as much as a native feel.

Comment: None of them are available on a basic Windows install! Note that OP is working on an application which will be released on Multiple platforms (OS X, **Windows** devices, iOS).

Comment: I am no software programmer, but is it not possible to use two different fonts, depending on the platform?

Comment: @e-sushi Hmm... Do people not use different fonts when doing multi platform applications?

Comment: @Brendan When doing multi-platform designs, the optimal goal is to use resources available on *all* systems natively, to ensure that the design and UX is the same across all devices. Second best option is to find *"similar alternatives"* which only differ minimally from each other. (As an example, the later is reflected in CSS font-stacks … different fonts with a similar size, weight and look.) Beyond these two options, a designer has only one option left: abandon the idea of *"same look across all devices"* — unless it's an option to *"install"* resources that aren't natively available.

Comment: Hi @Brendan. Since what version of OS X are Geneva, Gill Sans and Futura available to use? I guess I'll use a system-dependant stack of fonts and these sound and look ok for OS X but I am not sure which versions of it come with these?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look Google font in the sans serif category http://www.google.com/fonts

Comment: Google's font repository does not represent the fonts installed on osX, iOS, and Windows devices…

Comment: Thank you @FerdiCildiz. I will see although fonts I've seen so far lack certain "details".

Answer (score 0):

**Arial** is present on most systems. It's hard to fail using that font as your basic sans-serif font for multi-platform designs.

As far as I know *"Arial"* is the only sans-serif font which is natively installed on all 3 systems — iOS, osX, and Windows. If Arial doesn't suit your needs, you might have to opt-in for *"font stacks"* (which group different fonts with the same characteristics and the same visual appearance). In case you don't know: there is a good base of font-stacks to be found in the realms of "CSS font stacks" if you could need some grouped font names to get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much @e-sushi. You seem to be right about availability of Arial but it doesn't fit the design well. So I will go with the "font-stack" logic.

Comment: @Phil Glad I could help.